# XML Data into SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I'm hoping someone can help me out. I receive a weekly xml document that includes the below data. I need to create a table in SQL Server to store this data and every week reload the table with the new data. Can someone please suggest the easiest way to get this done. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<report>


-<report_header>

<c1>PROJECTNUMBER</c1>

<c2>PROJECTNAME</c2>

<c3>CHART_FIELD</c3>

<c4>PROJECT_SATUS</c4>

<c5>Anticipated_Final_Cost</c5>

<c6>Approved_Budget_AFC</c6>

<c7>Budget_Balance</c7>

<c8>Change_Order_Requests</c8>

<c9>Committed_Pending_Committments</c9>

<c10>Committed_to_Date</c10>

<c11>Current_Approved_Budget</c11>

<c12>Current_CBO_Budget</c12>

<c13>Exposure</c13>

<c14>Pending_Commitments</c14>

<c15>Total_Invoiced</c15>

<c16>Total_Paid</c16>

</report_header>


-<report_row>

<c1>10001</c1>

<c2>334 East 25th Street LL11-98</c2>

<c3>SOM01-55-A-86000-NYUPG-100457</c3>

<c4>View-Only</c4>

<c5>2,010,176.43</c5>

<c6>189,823.57</c6>

<c7>189,823.57</c7>

<c8>0.00</c8>

<c9>2,010,176.43</c9>

<c10>2,011,762.80</c10>

<c11>2,200,000.00</c11>

<c12>2,200,000.00</c12>

<c13>0.00</c13>

<c14>-1,586.37</c14>

<c15>2,010,176.93</c15>

<c16>2,010,176.93</c16>

</report_row>


-<report_row>

<c1>10002</c1>

<c2>New BDF - HJD</c2>

<c3>HOS01-55-H-86000-NYUPG-100458</c3>

<c4>Active</c4>

<c5>1,249,096.11</c5>

<c6>-429,096.11</c6>

<c7>-429,096.11</c7>

<c8>0.00</c8>

<c9>1,249,096.11</c9>

<c10>1,289,648.59</c10>

<c11>820,000.00</c11>

<c12>820,000.00</c12>

<c13>0.00</c13>

<c14>-40,552.48</c14>

<c15>1,213,091.02</c15>

<c16>1,213,091.02</c16>

</report_row>


-<report_row>

<c1>10003</c1>

<c2>Replace Humidification Systems - OR Day Surgery</c2>

<c3>HOS01-55-T-86000-NYUPG-100474</c3>

<c4>Active</c4>

<c5>1,162,698.70</c5>

<c6>337,301.30</c6>

<c7>337,301.30</c7>

<c8>0.00</c8>

<c9>1,162,698.70</c9>

<c10>1,153,745.00</c10>

<c11>1,500,000.00</c11>

<c12>1,500,000.00</c12>

<c13>0.00</c13>

<c14>8,953.70</c14>

<c15>39,610.00</c15>

<c16>7,795.00</c16>

</report_row>
```

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your report is quite easy to query. The section with `report_header` is not more than the captions to the numbered columns of the `report_row`-section.

You query this with `nodes('/report/report_row')`.

Regrettfully your decimal numbers *within* the XML are not casteable directly due to the commas. Try it like this:

Your XML

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report>
  <report_header>
    <c1>PROJECTNUMBER</c1>
    <c2>PROJECTNAME</c2>
    <c3>CHART_FIELD</c3>
    <c4>PROJECT_SATUS</c4>
    <c5>Anticipated_Final_Cost</c5>
    <c6>Approved_Budget_AFC</c6>
    <c7>Budget_Balance</c7>
    <c8>Change_Order_Requests</c8>
    <c9>Committed_Pending_Committments</c9>
    <c10>Committed_to_Date</c10>
    <c11>Current_Approved_Budget</c11>
    <c12>Current_CBO_Budget</c12>
    <c13>Exposure</c13>
    <c14>Pending_Commitments</c14>
    <c15>Total_Invoiced</c15>
    <c16>Total_Paid</c16>
  </report_header>
  <report_row>
    <c1>10001</c1>
    <c2>334 East 25th Street LL11-98</c2>
    <c3>SOM01-55-A-86000-NYUPG-100457</c3>
    <c4>View-Only</c4>
    <c5>2,010,176.43</c5>
    <c6>189,823.57</c6>
    <c7>189,823.57</c7>
    <c8>0.00</c8>
    <c9>2,010,176.43</c9>
    <c10>2,011,762.80</c10>
    <c11>2,200,000.00</c11>
    <c12>2,200,000.00</c12>
    <c13>0.00</c13>
    <c14>-1,586.37</c14>
    <c15>2,010,176.93</c15>
    <c16>2,010,176.93</c16>
  </report_row>
  <report_row>
    <c1>10002</c1>
    <c2>New BDF - HJD</c2>
    <c3>HOS01-55-H-86000-NYUPG-100458</c3>
    <c4>Active</c4>
    <c5>1,249,096.11</c5>
    <c6>-429,096.11</c6>
    <c7>-429,096.11</c7>
    <c8>0.00</c8>
    <c9>1,249,096.11</c9>
    <c10>1,289,648.59</c10>
    <c11>820,000.00</c11>
    <c12>820,000.00</c12>
    <c13>0.00</c13>
    <c14>-40,552.48</c14>
    <c15>1,213,091.02</c15>
    <c16>1,213,091.02</c16>
  </report_row>
  <report_row>
    <c1>10003</c1>
    <c2>Replace Humidification Systems - OR Day Surgery</c2>
    <c3>HOS01-55-T-86000-NYUPG-100474</c3>
    <c4>Active</c4>
    <c5>1,162,698.70</c5>
    <c6>337,301.30</c6>
    <c7>337,301.30</c7>
    <c8>0.00</c8>
    <c9>1,162,698.70</c9>
    <c10>1,153,745.00</c10>
    <c11>1,500,000.00</c11>
    <c12>1,500,000.00</c12>
    <c13>0.00</c13>
    <c14>8,953.70</c14>
    <c15>39,610.00</c15>
    <c16>7,795.00</c16>
  </report_row>
</report>';
```

--The query:

```
SELECT r.value('c1[1]','int') AS PROJECTNUMBER
      ,r.value('c2[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PROJECTNAME
      ,r.value('c3[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CHART_FIELD
      ,r.value('c4[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PROJECT_SATUS
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c5[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Anticipated_Final_Cost
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c6[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Approved_Budget_AFC
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c7[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Budget_Balance
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c8[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Change_Order_Requests
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c9[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Committed_Pending_Committments
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c10[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Committed_to_Date
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c11[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Current_Approved_Budget
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c12[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Current_CBO_Budget
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c13[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Exposure
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c14[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Pending_Commitments
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c15[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Total_Invoiced
      ,CAST(REPLACE(r.value('c16[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','') AS decimal(14,4)) AS Total_Paid
FROM @xml.nodes('/report/report_row') AS A(r)
```